# Nativescript Vue - binding a string to Label style attribute does not work

Tags: vue.js, styles, nativescript, bind

I just created a blank Nativescript Vue project (Typescript) and tried to bind a string to the type attribute of a Label - does not work (style gets completely ignored). I also tried in Nativescript Playground, same result.

Example Code is:

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Example" />
        <StackLayout>
            <Label style="font-size: 34" text="WORKS" />
            <Label :style="myStyle" text="DOES NOT WORK" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                myStyle: "font-size: 34"
            };
        }
    };
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

You can reproduce in Nativescript Vue Playground. On my Mac I'm using *Nativescript 8.1.2* with *nativescript-vue 2.9.0*.

I would expect it should be possible to do something like this. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a computed style with the bind mechanic, you need a [styleObject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1) consisting of the rule-name as key, and the value as... well the value.

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Example" />
        <StackLayout>
            <Label style="font-size: 34" text="WORKS" />
            <Label :style="myStyle" text="DOES NOT WORK" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                myStyle: {
                  font-size: '34px'
                },
            };
        }
    };
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check it this way is 100% working.
The object syntax is often used in conjunction with computed properties that return objects.

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Example" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label style="font-size: 34" text="WORKS" />
        <Label :style="styleObject" text="DOES NOT WORK" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                styleObject:{
              font-size: '34px'
            },
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```